# Strikethrough an item on a Listview

Tags: android

I need to put a strikethrough on the text after the item has been checked. I found solutions that use `setPaintFlags(descriptionView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);`. I don't use a textview but instead use `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` for my listview so how do I solve this? Here is my entire code:

```
public class Surv_list extends Fragment {

    final String[] OPSys = new String[]{"item1","item2","item3","item4"
    };
    ListView myList;
    Button getChoice, clearAll;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyUserChoice" ;
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlay, container, false);

        myList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        clearAll = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.clearall);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, OPSys);
        myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES)){
            LoadSelections();
        }
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                SaveSelections();

            }

        });


        clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ClearSelections();
            }
        });
return rootView;
    }

    private void SaveSelections() {
// save the selections in the shared preference in private mode for the user

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String savedItems = getSavedItems();
        prefEditor.putString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), savedItems);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }

    private String getSavedItems() {
        String savedItems = "";
        int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (this.myList.isItemChecked(i)) {
                if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                    savedItems += "," + this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);

                } else {
                    savedItems += this.myList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return savedItems;
    }

    private void LoadSelections() {
// if the selections were previously saved load them

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(MyPREFERENCES.toString())) {

            String savedItems = sharedpreferences.getString(MyPREFERENCES.toString(), "");
            selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));

            int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String currentItem = (String) myList.getAdapter()
                        .getItem(i);
                if (selectedItems.contains(currentItem)) {
                    myList.setItemChecked(i, true);

                } else {
                    myList.setItemChecked(i, false);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void ClearSelections() {
// user has clicked clear button so uncheck all the items
        int count = this.myList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            this.myList.setItemChecked(i, false);
        }
// also clear the saved selections
        SaveSelections();
    }

}
```

any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you have to use custom adapter doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter for your list view and in the getview method of the adpater take the handle of textview . Based on your condition you can combine the already available code to strikeout the text view.

Answer (score 0):

for making your own view attributes in list view, you have to make a custom Adapter other than using default adapter. there is no way you can do this using default adapter. [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) you can learn how to make custom adapter. also I would suggest you to use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of ListView